# Search over partial,repetable,dn attribute

Tags: search, ldap, openldap

I'm currently facing to a dn based search problem.

I work on a client LDAP so I can't modify the structure and I have a readOnly full access.

In this LDAP the users a grouped by permission.

Let's imagine 4 permissions with follow uid :

```
uid=APP1#Admin#feature,ou=permission,ou=client,ou=fr
uid=APP1#User#other feature,ou=permission,ou=client,ou=fr 
uid=APP2#Admin,ou=permission,ou=client,ou=fr
uid=APP3#Admin,ou=permission,ou=client,ou=fr
```

APP1, APP2 and APP3 are three diferents applications

Now imagine 3 users :

First

```
uid=jdoe,ou=user,ou=client,ou=fr
dnPermission=uid=APP2#Admin,ou=permission,ou=client,ou=fr
dnPermission=uid=APP1#User#other feature,ou=permission,ou=client,ou=fr
dnPermission=uid=APP3#Admin,ou=permission,ou=client,ou=fr
```

Second

```
uid=jdupont,ou=user,ou=client,ou=fr
dnPermission=uid=APP1#Admin#feature,ou=permission,ou=client,ou=fr
dnPermission=uid=APP2#Admin,ou=permission,ou=client,ou=fr
```

Third

```
uid=mhari,ou=user,ou=client,ou=fr
dnPermission=uid=APP2#Admin#feature,ou=permission,ou=client,ou=fr
dnPermission=uid=APP3#Admin,ou=permission,ou=client,ou=fr
```

Each application can have many permissions and the list of permission is not stable in the time.

My aim is to get all user having permission on APP1 with a single query.

I can't get all users and filter after because the LDAP has 24K+ users and my application concern only 75 users.

My first idea was to handle dn like string and user follow query :

```
(&(objectclass=people)(dnPermission=uid=APP1*))
```

or

```
(&(objectclass=people)(dnPermission=APP1*))
```

but both return me 0 results.

Is possible ?
How ?

NB1 : people is a subclass of standard Person class with no technical account

NB2 : dnPermission is a DN link, not a full text attribute.

Comment: The backslash is incorrect. Remove it.

Comment: It's fixed , it was a mistake to copy / paste

Comment: What is the actual value of `attr` in the search string, and what is a sample value? Normally group names are DN-valued.

Comment: In my case attr is named dnPermission. Users can have multiple dnPermission attributes.
`dnPermission=uid=Admin#App1,ou=permission,ou=client,ou=fr dnPermission=uid=Admin#App2,ou=permission,ou=client,ou=fr`

Comment: And what is a sample value of XXX in the search string? I should not have had to ask any of these three questions. You should have already provided the actual data in your question.

Comment: Sorry, my exposure of the problem was crystal clear for me because I work on it for two weeks. I have fully rephrased my question with more details and examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there is no such things as an objectClass 'People'.
The standard object class for people in LDAP is 'Person' and its subclasses 'organizationalPerson' and 'inetOrgPerson'

Comment: In fact I work with custom schemas . So class people exist but contains only natural person ( not technical accounts ). 
Conversely Person contain all accounts.

Comment: If dnPermission has a syntax of DN, then a filter (dnPermission=xxx*) is UNDEFINED and will return zero result, because there is no such thing as a DistinguishedNameSubString Matching Rule. DNs can only be matched by equality.

Comment: This is the answer I feared.